# how to prove the differentiability of multi variable function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, continuity

i have a function $f(x,y)= x^3\sin(1/x^2) + y^3\sin(1/y^2)$ when $xy\ne0$ but when $xy=0$ then the function is zero . Now if I need to show that the function is differentiable at $(0,0)$. I know that the partial derivatives exist and equal to zero and are continuous so I used this notation to prove my differentiability but  I don't know if it's correct to say that? could I get clear guidance on how should I proceed? any help is appreciated

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm) to format your posts.  To begin with, surround math expressions (including numbers) with `$` signs and use `_` for subscripts.  `$x_1$` comes out as $x_1$.

Comment: If you have a theorem that says "continuous partials at a point implies it's differentiable at that point", you can use it. But I doubt that condition applies here. Please add your work/details for "I know that the partial derivatives exist and equal to zero and are continuous"